# EmberData, how do i prepend an object into the store after save, instead of appending it?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

As the title say, after save a new model, how do i prepend in the store instead of appending?

Right now, creating a record will push the new object in the store, at the end of the existing objects. I need to push it at the start, how do you do that?

Comment: Why do you need it? Wouldn't it be easier to sort if before displaying or whatever?

Comment: I have X records loaded in the cache already that i am displaying in a list  and then i am adding the Yth record and i don't want to make another call to server to load the X records once again since they didn't change anyway. That is why i want the Yth record to be prepended not appended. Right now, this new record is pushed at the end of the actual list and i don't want this, i want to find a way to be oushed at the start of the list, otherwise i should query the server once again.

Comment: You don't need to query server again. You can have your data array sorted by some property like `order`. You push new record with `order = 0`, then you get all current records (except of new record) with `store.peekAll`, increment their `order` by 1, then you need to have some observer or computed property which would re-sort array in your view-layer (component or controller).

Comment: I investigated how would you need to do it and it would involve messing with Store, InternalModel, RecordArrayManager (updating live arrays), OrderedSet.

Comment: @DanielKmak - Thanks for the suggestion, i managed to get it to work  using Ember.computed.sort after all, was simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I created a Ember Twiddle where each new record is inserted at the beginning of the arrays. It should help you - [demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/15abfa383febdc0a10ba?openFiles=initializers.reopen-store.js%2Capplication.template.hbs).

Basically you need to alter `DS.RecordArrayManager._addRecordToRecordArray` and change:

```
array.addInternalModel(record);
```

To:

```
array.addInternalModel(record, 0);
```

If you would like to create some specific store method like `store.createRecordAtBeginning` you would have to pass some data along with `InternalModel` through many classes and access it in `DS.RecordArrayManager._addRecordToRecordArray` to determine at which position you need to insert.

Comment: I prefer your original suggestion of `Ember.computed.sort`, much less fiddly.

Comment: Yeah, me too, but idea of appending at beginning of live arrays is pretty interesting. Always exciting to see how Ember internals work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get it to work using Ember.computed.sort:

```
// controller:
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   sortProp: ['position:asc'],
   sortedModels: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProp'),
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each sortedModels as |mdl|}}...
```